# Making an app that streams videos to Blackberry Playbook?

Tags: android

I am trying to work on an app that streams videos from a website into an app. So, it's like watching those videos in the app, not the website. How would you do this? Can someone point me to a tutorial or explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depends on what framework you are developing for. You need to provide more info if you want real answers. 
For example, if you are using the native sdk to develop for the playbook (C/C++), info regarding streaming video can be found here:
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/documentation/video_playback_overview_1935223_11.html
May not be for streaming specifically, but its a start.

If you are developing and AIR application (Flex), well then thats library question. Just off the top of my head, you would probably use the NetStream class. Documentation found here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Again, need more info to give you a good answer.

Comment: Sorry about that Theo. I am using the Android plug-in developer tools in Eclipse. I was just curious on how to do this.

Comment: Ok well first off, I highly recommend that if you plan to stream video in your app, you develop a NATIVE playbook application as opposed to a ported android one. Not only will this help with performance, but honestly, taking the time to develop natively is extremely worthwhile, especially for the playbook.

Comment: As for how to stream video, that i cannot say as I only have experience with the native libraries. So this is more of an android development question rather than a playbook question. I highly recommend you develop native. Highly. Highly. Highly.

Comment: Ok. I will look into that. I have been using Eclipse because I have always programmed in Java mostly. I will work on native android apps and then try implementing streaming video. Thanks for that.